# how can i access one page through 2 different sessions?

Tags: php

I have two pages admin page and a super admin page..
i just want to have rights of admin page too.. when i login as a super admin

currently to login admin page i use

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']))            //if admin not in session
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}
```

and this works fine
but when i use this condition

```
if((!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) || (!isset($_SESSION['super_admin'])))       //either      admin or super admin is not in session
 {
header ("Location: home.php");
}
```

which means either admin or super admin can have access to this page ... (this condition is what i think should be)
I login as admin and i get the following error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly.

Is there any way to access admin's page when I'm in super admin session?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? You would have to be a bit more specific..

Comment: uploaded the error image (firefox)

Comment: that is actually the image ... :) (the page isn't redirecting properly)

Comment: I'm sorry about that, you have no html code above this rule right?
Try to remove the space behind Location:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) || (!isset($_SESSION['super_admin'])))
    // redirect
```

This means you're refusing anyone that is not "admin" *and* "super_admin" at the same time! You probably meant to use `&&` to refuse "anyone who's not an admin *and* not a super admin either".

---

I'm not sure why you're getting the redirect error out of this, my guess would be that `home.php` determines you're logged in and redirects you back to the admin page that refuses you again etc. So you probably have two errors to fix - the condition and the redirect cycle.